# Как правильно сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Между ушей" или "между ушами"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В современном русском языке предлог "между" согласуетс с тв.падежом- между ушами, но в старом русском этот предлог согласовался с существительными множественного числа в род.падеже, т.е. "между ушей", как "между двух огней". Чаще род.падеж с существит. множ.числа с предлогом "между" используется в перен. значении. Если этот предлог используется в смысле "пропустить", тогда будет "между ушей". А если в смысле "... расположены глаза", тогда- "между ушами".

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще предлог МЕЖ. Так вот он как раз требует после себя родительного падежа: меж глаз, меж ушей. Сравните: *удар промеж глаз* :-)) Семантически этот предлог синоним МЕЖДУ.

Answer (score 0):

Если пропустить, то "мимо ушей", а не "между ушей". Я не совсем представляю, как это выглядит: "между ушей" и "между ушами". "Между пальцами" могу представить. Так вообще говорят?

Comment: >>>Я не совсем представляю, как это выглядит: 

Между ушами у котенка было белое пятно.

Comment: уши ведь не только у людей есть :-)